# Python: Renaming first 5 files of a folder

Tags: python, regex, rename, os.walk

I dont know if this can be done or not, but is there a way that I can rename only the first 5 files in a folder? I know that I can use the os.listdir() or os.walk() to walk through the entire folder, but I only need to rename the first 5 files. I am able to use a Regex to match the files, but the problem is is that there are other files that match the same Regex. Does anyone have any suggestions?
The file name takes the form of "Test Run 1 4-29-2016 2 07 56 PM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the result from `listdir`:

```
os.listdir(os.curdir)[:5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it would be something easy

Answer (score 0):

[glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) will allow you to filter files using wild cards

> **glob.glob(pathname)** 
>   Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).  No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

```
glob.glob('*.gif')[:5]
```